# Como puedo modificar o eliminar codigo protegido en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

[image]

Necesito borrar tanto la clase principal de esta interfaz grafica de usuario creada con jframe en netbeans, como tambien el resto del codigo que esta protegido, ya que estoy intentando comunicar la capa de interfaz grafica de usuario con la lógica.

Comment: Está protegido porque lo genera al usar la interfaz gráfica arrastrando elementos a la ventana, tendrás que borrarlos desde la propia ventana o montarla a mano sin usar la vista gráfica.